# Problem with a CSS position relative "list"

Tags: css

So, I have a div("NormalInventory") with many childrens(32), each child has size of 85px x 85px except for one div, this div has size of 175px x 175px. Each div has attribute position: relative & display: inline-block, so it is a css "list". But because there is one div that is bigger than the others, there are empty spaces. And I don't know how to fill those free spaces with boxes.

A Screenshot how it looks:

[image]

A Screenshot how it should look(edited in paint):

[image]

html:

```html
<div class="NormalInventory">
    <div class="children">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.NormalInventory {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    .InventoryItemPlaceholder {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #070707E6;
        left: -5px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this effect using CSS Grid.  You won't need to use inline-block for your elements.  Just apply a `display: grid` to you parent element, and give it columns of `repeat(4, 1fr)` which means it will give you 4 equal columns of 1 fraction each.  Grid will handle the rows.

For the big element, give it a value of `span 2` on both `grid-column` and `grid-row`.

```css
.App {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 4px;
  max-width: fit-content;
}

.box {
  background: black;
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
}

.big {
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
    <div class="App">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box big"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .parent{
      display: flex;
      width: 355px;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      position: relative;
    }

    .child{
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    background: black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .child--big{
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 90px;
    background: black;
    }
```

```html
    <div class = "parent">
      <div class = "child"></div>  
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child"></div> 
      <div class = "child--big"></div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier with grid:

```
.container {  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 85px 85px 85px 85px;
  grid-template-rows: 85px 85px 85px 85px 85px 85px 85px 85px;
  gap: 5px 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a1 b1 c1 d1"
    "a2 bigBlock bigBlock d2"
    "a3 bigBlock bigBlock d3"
    "a4 b4 c4 d4"
    "a5 b5 c5 d5"
    "a6 b6 c6 d6"
    "a7 b7 c7 d7"
    "a8 b8 c8 d8";
}
.bigBlock { grid-area: bigBlock; }
.a1 { grid-area: a1; }
.a2 { grid-area: a2; }
.a3 { grid-area: a3; }
.a4 { grid-area: a4; }
.a5 { grid-area: a5; }
.a6 { grid-area: a6; }
.a7 { grid-area: a7; }
.a8 { grid-area: a8; }
.b1 { grid-area: b1; }
.c1 { grid-area: c1; }
.d1 { grid-area: d1; }
.d2 { grid-area: d2; }
.d3 { grid-area: d3; }
.b4 { grid-area: b4; }
.b5 { grid-area: b5; }
.b6 { grid-area: b6; }
.b7 { grid-area: b7; }
.b8 { grid-area: b8; }
.c4 { grid-area: c4; }
.c5 { grid-area: c5; }
.c6 { grid-area: c6; }
.c7 { grid-area: c7; }
.c8 { grid-area: c8; }
.d4 { grid-area: d4; }
.d5 { grid-area: d5; }
.d6 { grid-area: d6; }
.d7 { grid-area: d7; }
.d8 { grid-area: d8; }
```